# Future in the past expressed by simple past?

Tags: future-tense, past-simple

This is the original text I have:

> October 31, 1906: "No, you had not told me that you **did not expect** to make any flights this year." ([Source](https://www.loc.gov/resource/mwright.03201/?sp=19))

Does the sentence have the same meaning as:

1) No, you had not told me that you **would not expect** to make any flights this year.

or

2) No, you **did not tell** me that you **would not expect** to make any flights this year.

**UPDATE**

My grammar problem is like this:

- You had told me that you expected to make a flight.
- You had told me that you would expect to make a flight.

"you expected" sounds to me like a future in the past and I do not understand why it is like this and not "would expect".

Or simply the meaning of "You had told me that you expected to make a flight." is  "You expected to make a flight, this is what you had told me."

Answer (score 1):

If you use the past perfect it's assumed you want to relate the timing of two events:

> No you had not told me you were not going to go **before you walked away**.

Here I want to relate the timing of "telling me something" and "walking away".  One comes before the other.

If you don't mean to do this, then the simple past is sufficient:

> No you did not tell me you were not going to go.

In the letter it's not clear what the other event the writer wants to relate to -- probably in reference to the "deal with the French people" or other business, or maybe it goes along with "I have been waiting all summer ..."

Either way I'm curious what a supplier of bee keeping equipment has to do with the Wright Brothers.  Now I have to do some research :)

[Some history](http://rootcandles.com/wright-brothers-story/)

[More history](http://www.pbs.org/wgbh/nova/wright/reporter.html)

Comment: I have added an update. Your explanation might be the right one but your example: "No you had not told me you were not going to go before you walked away." has a future in the past, "you were not going to go" while the October 31, 1906 text does not have it.

Comment: @RobertWerner  your question seems to focus on the past perfect vs. the past simple.  Whatever I told you -- future action, past action, etc. -- isn't going to affect which you choose.  All of that reported speech acts as an independent subclause.  It's confusing because of the double negative -- "you had not told me you would not expect, etc."  but that whole 'future in the past" question is only a distraction.

Comment: Possible I was not clear enough. My question is not about "you had not told me" (see the update). I understand why it is like this. The Wrights made Root understand they would fly during 1906 and on October 30, 1906 they denied that they had promised flights during that year. My question is about "you did not expect" which sounds like a "you would not expect".

Comment: @RobertWerner  Well, you bolded "had" and "did" so that's what I focused on.  But anyway -- "you would not expect" is reported speech of what was *actually* said at that time.  Even though the speech was in the past, you don't have to back-shift.  I probably would have written, "you didn't tell me you were not expecting" which is back-shifted.

Comment: "I probably would have written, "you didn't tell me you were not expecting" which is back-shifted." OK. In the future I will say like you and avoid a construction like that used by A. I. Root.

Comment: @RobertWerner yeah keep in mind this was written in 1906 when correspondence was *much* more formal than it is today.  Although this particular letter is relatively informal for the time, it's still dated by modern standards.   Nowadays the letter would be much shorter, or even a text to the Wright Brothers:  "Hey guys!  I guess I goofed and misunderstood that you weren't going to fly this year.  My bad!"

Comment: One more question. Is "you had not told me that you did not expect to make any flights" reported speech or not? From your answer: (""you would not expect" is reported speech of what was actually said at that time. Even though the speech was in the past, you don't have to back-shift."), I understand that it is not or this is a special case where "would not expect" does not work?!

Comment: "you didn't tell me you were not expecting" looks to refer to a single moment in the past. "you had not told me that you did not expect" appears to be something about multiple moments in the past. It could be a contraction of "Last month, you didn't tell me you were not expecting", "Two month ago, you didn't tell me you were not expecting" and so on. This is just my guess.

Comment: @RobertWerner  there's not enough information to make that assumption.    He's only saying they didn't tell him, he doesn't say how many opportunities they had to tell him.  Also I guess *technically* it's reported speech, but now that I think about it, you can't report speech that someone *didn't* say, can you?

Comment: The Wrights had many opportunities because Root sent a lot of letters asking the two inventors not to forget to invite him if they planned flights.

Comment: Sure but that information is not included in this specific letter.  We can't tell from context how many times he contacted them -- we know they had a good relationship, and perhaps a business partnership, but not a lot more.  The use of "had not told me" doesn't indicate anything.

Comment: It is usu. just "will" that shifts to "would"  when the future shifts into the future-in-the-past. Other expressions of the future backshift differently.  E.g. "I will make some flights this year" (present expression of future intention) becomes "I would" (conditional, aka future-in-the-past).  But "I'm going to make some..." becomes "I was going to make some..."; and "I expect to make some..." becomes "I expected to make some...". (Still, it would be possible to say "I would expect" as a *present*, or past, expression of future intent with the *would* expressing tentativeness or politeness.)

Answer (score 1):

To better understand the problem, try removing all those negatives: "You [had] told me that you expected to fly." or "You [had] told me that you would expect to fly."

You could also convert to reported speech: 'You [had] told me "We expect to fly."' or 'You [had] told me "We will expect to fly."'

'Will expect' is odd because 'expect' is already about the future, and the same applies to 'would expect'.

Pluperfect 'had told' shifts the telling farther into the past.  Compare:
"He sat down.  He ate too much." and "He sat down.  He had eaten too much."
The 2nd scenario implies that he sat down because he ate too much, because the eating happened before the sitting.

Answer (score 1):

REPORTED SPEECH
A) "do not expect" becomes "did not expect"
October 1, 1906:

Person 1: "I **do not expect** to make any flights this year."

October 31, 1906:

Person 2: "I thought you had told me that **you did not expect** to make any flights this year."

B) *will not expect* becomes *would not expect*

Person 1: I expect I will make some flights this year.

Person 2: Yes, you told me that you thought you would make some flights this year.

In reported speech, *do* becomes *did* and *will* becomes *would*.

*would* here is not a conditional. It is the past tense of *will*.